# Reduce only generically correct?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

While it is clearly said in the Mathematica documentation that functions like FullSimplify yield only 'generically correct' results, I have found no mention of such restrictions for Reduce. However, consider the following two examples (Input):

`Gamma[x] \[Element] Reals`

`Gamma[0] \[Element] Reals`

`Reduce[ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals,   Gamma[x] \[Element] Reals], x, Reals]`

The output (Version 12.0.0) will be:

`Gamma[x] \[Element] Reals`

`False`

`True`

of which the last output is incorrect. The second example is even more problematic, as Mathematica tells us that Not[x!=0 || y!=0] is a contradiction (Input):

`expr = Implies[x == y, 1/x - 1/y == 0]`

`Reduce[expr, {x, y}, Reals]`

`% // Simplify`

`Reduce[Not[expr], {x, y}, Reals]`

Output is:

`x == y \[Implies] 1/x - 1/y == 0`

`x < 0 || (x == 0 && (y < 0 || y > 0)) || x > 0`

`x != 0 || y != 0`

`False`

**Questions:**

Is there a way to *always* get correct answers to queries such as those in the two examples above (using Reduce or any other Mathematica commands)? If not, is there a way to be *always* notified whenever the result is only 'generically correct'?

Comment: From you post is not clear where is input and where is output.

Comment: How about `expr = ForAll[{x, y}, Implies[x == y, 1/x - 1/y == 0]];

Resolve[expr, {x, y}, Reals]` which correctly results in `False` (division by `0` is impossible)?